# Replace missing values in list from second list using python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider you have two lists (or columns in a pandas DataFrame), each containing some null values. You want a single list that replaces the null values in one list with the corresponding non-null values of the other if one exists.

Example:

```
s1 = [1, NaN, NaN]
s2 = [NaN, NaN, 3]
## some function
result = [1, NaN, 3]
```

Assume that if both lists are non-null at some position then they match, so we need not worry about resolving conflicts. If so, I know I can solve it with a list comprehension:

```
[x if ~np.isnan(x) else y for (x,y) in zip(s1,s2)]
```

or if s1 and s2 are columns in a pandas DataFrame df, then we can use similar logic and the apply function:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.s1 if ~np.isnan(x.s1) else x.s2, axis=1)
```

but is there a cleaner way to do this, perhaps using some of the pandas functionality? What is this kind of operation even called? It is kind of like a union, but preserves ordering and null values when lacking an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas fillna functionality to fill missing values from other columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,np.nan],[np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,3]],columns=['c1','c2'])
df['c1'].fillna(df['c2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently. You may have to adapt what I put below depending on the structure of your column values.

```python
import pandas as pd

# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 'b', None, 'd', 'e', None, None]})

# null positions and list of values to replace nulls with
nulls = df[pd.isnull(df.col)].index
goodies = ['c', 'f', 'g']

# replace nulls with empty strings
df['col'].fillna('', inplace=True)

# augment empty strings to something we can keep track of
SEP = '_'
df['col'] = df.col + pd.Series([SEP + str(i) for i in df.index])

# create map to turn bad values good and then perform replacement
salvation = {bad: good for bad, good in zip(df.ix[nulls].col, goodies)}
df.replace(salvation, inplace=True)

# remove everything including and after SEP string
df['col'] = df.col.apply(lambda s: s.split(SEP)[0])
```

Note that in my example the column contained string values, so depending on your data types you should convert to strings using `astype()` method and then back to what you want when you're done. Also, you may need to change the `SEP` so you don't split up your values in an unwanted manner in the last line.